# Alamofire extra argument 'method' in call from Alamofire example

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I would like to state that I've tried every single example and scanned the plethora of other questions exactly like mine to no avail, so I have NO CHOICE but to post.

Xcode: 8.3.1 (8E1000a)
Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.51 clang-802.0.41)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
OSX 10.12.4

Please see the code:

Note: This is embedded in a function, the parameters "email" and "password" are strings and are available, I also tried setting static string values.

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://website.what.com/api/v1/login")
    let params: Parameters = ["email": email, "password":password]

    // This Works
    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .post, parameters: params)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print(response)
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
            }
    }


    // This one returns: "Extra argument Method in call"

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "foo": [1,2,3],
        "bar": [
            "baz": "qux"
        ]
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

The primary I am confident in posting again - the second example was taken straight from the Alamofire github README.

If I am missing something - as in incorrectly encoding a parameter (which I copied directly from Alamofire's github page) or something.

Alternately, if someone can provide me a working sample on Swift 3.1 which allows me to use JSON, Headers, and POST Method.

The first "working" method does not have headers, I am not sure if I can use that example with additional parameters or not?

Sorry for the trouble, very very fresh swift learner who is diving head-first into a complicated world.

Comment: is your pod up to date ? If your cocoapods is not up to date it will download the earlier version of alamofire , in that case these might happen.

Comment: I am not using pods - I imported the project, built Alamofire and started using it in my code.  If you think I *REALLY* should use the pod, I will switch it over.

Comment: yes mate, eventually you have to rely on pod, so start using it.